# Trying to detect new joiners of a Facebook group, so I can send them a welcome message via the API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way of sending a automated welcome message to a user
after he/she joins a facebook group?

I have tried searching facebook developers graph api but was out of luck. If any one has any idea please share

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no API i'm aware of that will notify you when new users join a group, so you won't be able to do this